# Conditionally updating roles in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, role

I actually want to create an easy function but it doesn't seem to work.
I want that when a user logs to his account on Wordpress to change his role (subscriber -> directory_1) on some condition (easy in this case to test, it should change everytime, but still not working).
Here is my code :

```
add_action('wp_login', 'update_roles');

function update_roles()
{
   global $wpdb;
   $author = wp_get_current_user();
   if(current_user_can('subscriber'))
   {
       $author->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
       $author->add_role( 'directory_1' );
   }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `wp_update_user()` to update a user's role. After you have added a role using `add_role()`, you can do something like this:

```
function custom_update_roles( $user_login, $user ) {

    if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( "subscriber", $user->roles ) ) {
            $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user->ID, 'role' => 'directory_1' ) );

            if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
                // Error.
            } else {
                // Success.
            }
        } else {
            // This user is not a subscriber.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'custom_update_roles', 10, 2 );
```

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

Comment: Thx a lot! Although I get this error now : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare update_roles() (previously declared in functions.php:6)

Comment: Still get an error, but this time at the last line. Trying to understand the problem but can't seem to do so :/ : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in functions.php on line 248

Comment: I think that error might be unrelated to the code I've posted. Can you paste your functions.php code in pastebin.com?

Comment: Have a try of my updated code. If it doesn't work, try making "Subscriber" all lower case.

Comment: Have you set up the `directory_1` role using the `add_role()` function?

Comment: directory_1 already exist and is used by other users. I'd like that the function change automatically all the users with the role "subscriber" to "directory_1" when they login to the site. Thx again for the help!

Comment: Running with no error but it doesn't change the role of my test user. Not sure what to do to debug the code :-/ Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: After the last modification it works perfectly! Thank you so much!